# How to scale EKS Pods and Nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

In AWS console CloudWatch > Container Insights > Performance Monitoring. I selected EKS Pods. There are 2 charts: `Node CPU Utilization` and `Pod CPU Utilization`.

I have several images deployed.

During my load testing, `Node CPU Utilization` shows Image A at spiking up to 98%. However, `Pod CPU Utilization` shows Image A below 0.1%.

Anybody understands what does these 2 metrics mean? Does it mean I should increase the number of nodes instead of number of pods?

Example of the dashboard:

[image]

Comment: The node CPU might be surging because of other pods consuming CPU. Could it be that the POD CPU Utilization graph doesn't include all pods on that node?

Comment: You can also use `kubectl top pods` and `kubectl top nodes` to query the current resource usage directly from the cluster, instead of relying on cloud watch.

Comment: the node cpu utilization specified Image A was using 99%. But Image A in Pod CPU utilization was <0.1%. Unfortunately, the load test has ended and I can only reply on cloudwatch to analyze the data